# Dojo Localization - Doesn't translate and/or doesn't load

Tags: localization, dojo

I am trying to setup localization using dojo but can't get it working.

I have a folder structure like this:

```
Folder: locale
    - about.html
    - Folder: nls
        - about.js
        - Folder fr
            - about.js
```

This is the file that should be localized.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dojoConfig = {
        locale: 'fr'
    };
</script>
<script src="//servicesbeta.esri.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.4/js/dojo/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>
    require([
        "dojo/i18n",
        "dojo/i18n!./nls/about"
    ],function(
        i18n,
        nls
    ){
        console.log("Good Morning");
        console.log(dojoConfig);
        console.log(nls['hello']);
    });
</script> 
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

This is the output from the file:

[image]

I am expecting for the output to include `French Hello`, not `English Hello`.

If I change the require from:

```
require([
    "dojo/i18n",
    "dojo/i18n!./nls/about.js"
],function(
```

To:

```
require([
    "dojo/i18n",
    "dojo/i18n!./nls/about"
],function(
```

I get this output:

[image]

Not exactly sure what is going on here.

Why can't the first example find the French Localization?  It is being loaded and the local is being set.

The second example is more consistent with most of the dojo examples that I see.  What is up with this?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

---

For completeness, nls/about.js:

```
define({
    root: {
    hello: "English Hello"
    },
    "fr":true
});
```

and nls/fr/about.js:

```
define({
    root: {
    hello: "French Hello"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the root object from your nls/fr/about.js. It is only needed in the root file, because those are the strings that will be used if a locale-specific file is not found.

So your locale specific files should look like this:

```
define({
    hello: "French Hello"
});
```

For your second question: When you reference the file "about.js" you use a valid file path. When you reference "nls/about" you are referencing the AMD module, so you use a valid module path according to your package definitions. Either syntax is fine, but if you want to use the package path then try adding a package definition in your dojoConfig like so:

```
packages: [{
    name: "nls",
    location: "/nls"
}]
```

Comment: Right you are!  Removing the root element worked.  Thanks also for the clarification between the module path and the file path.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience in localization i have been doing it this way.

So what you are doing is basically correct but calling the `"dojo/i18n!./nls/about"`file is a bet unfamiliar for me so this is another way to do it.

var my_localization_object = i18n.getLocalization("locale", "about");

and you need to add the package to the dojoconfig:

```
var dojoConfig = {
        locale: 'fr',
packages: [
     //location should be a full qualified location.
  { name: "locale", location: "/JS/locale" }
],
  };
```

this way you will get an object back in the `my_localization_object` variable but the french locale so you can use the object to populate whatever you want.

And you about.js should look something like this:

```
define({
    root: ({
    //Whatever object you want
    }),

    "en": false,
    "en-gb": false,
    "en-us": true,
    "fr": false,

});
```